# Play : How to retrieve cache in my ActionTransformer

Tags: scala, caching, playframework-2.0

I am using Play 2.4 Scala. I use Action composition with `ActionTransformer` to have a User instance available in my `CustomAction`.

I want my `ActionTransformer` to retrieve things from cache. The `CacheApi` instance can only be retrieved by dependency injection and my `ActionTransformer` is an object (no DI).

Should I declare a `@Inject() (cache...)` in all my controllers then pass this cache instance explicitly in my `def index = CustomAction(cache) {...}` functions ?

Is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: I ended up mixing an appropriate trait in each controller, the trait has a val targetCache: CacheApi not defined. It requires adding specific @Inject() (cache...) for all controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an instance from guice by calling the injector directly:

```
val cache = Play.current.injector.instanceOf(classOf[CacheApi])
```

Be aware that this involves play's gobal state. As you probably know this will be deprecated in Play 3.0, so it is probably a good idea to use it sparingly. If anyone found a better approach, I'd be interested too...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this as service (outside controllers) :

```
@Singleton class ActionTransformer @Inject() (private val cache: CacheApi) {

    // Do what you want with the cache instance

        def getMyCachedClassFromCache : MyCachedClass = {
            cache.getOrElse[MyCachedClass](KEY_CACHE) {
                val myNewCachedClass = MyCachedClass()
                cache.set(KEY_CACHE, myNewCachedClass)
            }
        }
}
```